# How do I enter the Euro symbol in vim?

Tags: command-line, 16.04, vim, special-characters

I am running vim 7.4:

```
andrew@athens:~$ vim --version | head -n 2
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Jun 16 2016 10:50:38)
Included patches: 1-1689
```

And I need to routinely type in the Euro symbol. How do I do this easily and efficiently?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Ctrl-k = e
```

You can use it in "insert" mode.

---

Proof:

[image]

Comment: More info: https://vimtricks.com/p/insert-special-characters/
For EURO you could also use <Ctrl-k>Eu